# heat transfer between two concentric cylinders

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I want to develop a model for heat transfer between two concentric cylinders in contact, one being heated and the second one passively cooled, but I am not really sure, what way would be the best to do it.

My plan is to use two two heat capacitors with heat capacity according to each material and a heat conductor between them. But I'm not really sure, if putting heat conductor in-between the cylinders is the right thing to do as the two cylinders are touching and there is nothing separating them. How to then calculate what should be the thermal conductance then.

Thanks for all of your suggestions.

I tried to make a model of heat transfer between two concentric cylinders in contact, but don't know, what is the best way, to do it, with thermal conductor or without.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your boundary conditions. It sounds like you have a combination of heat flux (inner face) - thermal conductance (cylinder 1) - thermal conductance (cylinder 2) - heat transfer coefficient.
You should be able to find the thermal conductance (or equivalently resistance) of a hollow cylinder in a heat transfer textbook, or compute the formula with the help of one, which you can then put in the thermal conductance components' parameters.
For simple boundary conditions, this will probably even be an analytic solution.